# How do i return Json array using vertx routingcontext

Tags: json, router, vert.x

I'm writing api using vertx router, and i need my api to return list of json object, is it possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post a sample of the code that doesn't work, and we'll be happy to help you.

Comment: Yes, you can return list of JSON with vert.x. But you need to post a piece of code of what you have tried. It seems you are new to SO. Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, here is a full example with vert.x json abstraction:

```java
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    
    router.get("/foo")
        .handler(ctx -> {
          JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
          jsonArray.add(new JsonObject());
          jsonArray.add(new JsonObject());
          
          ctx.response()
            .setChunked(true)
            .setStatusCode(200)
            .end(jsonArray.toBuffer());
        });
    
    vertx
      .createHttpServer()
      .requestHandler(router)
      .listen(8080);
  }
}
```

In case you want to use your own library for json manipulation + pojos, you can work with strings instead when ending the request. e.g. with jackson:

```java
router.get("/foo")
    .handler(ctx -> {
      List<MyObject> myObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

      String myObjectListJsonStr = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myObjectList);

      ctx.response()
        .setChunked(true)
        .setStatusCode(200)
        .end(myObjectListJsonStr);
    });
```